# Numix: Only the circle theme seems to work

Tags: 15.04, unity-tweak-tool, numix

Somehow only the circle theme of Numix seems to work:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Numix option you have chosen in the first photo is FOR a GTK theme NOT  a icon theme.  According to The Numix creators  website the only icon themes they have are:

- Numix Sauqre ($1.50 USD)
- Numix Circle (free)
- Numix Shine(Free)
- Numix uTouch(Free)

Source: [Numix Website](https://numixproject.org)

Comment: I don't quite understand. There is nothing that tells it's for GTK. Shine and uTouch won't work. Square is 3.00$ in their store and I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: According to their site. Its listed under GTK Themes page.